# react-native AJAX&API - Render JSON data

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm really newbie to react. My question is how to iterate component and render json data. Here's my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { ScrollView, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { Divider } from 'react-native-elements';
import { limitUI04 } from 'uuid-js';


export default class SearchProperty extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      error: null,
      isLoaded: false,
      items: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("myapiendpoint", {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            items: result.data
          });
        },
        (error) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            error
          });
        }
      )
  }

  render() {
    const { error, isLoaded, items } = this.state;
    {
      items.map(key => {
        return (
          <Text>
            {key.id}
          </Text>
        )
      })
    }
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

My code above return error:

> Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: SearchProperty(...): Nothing
>   was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is
>   missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.

Please help

Comment: you are missing your return statement...

Comment: My return is there, inside the map method. @BensSteves

Comment: In my code I made componentDidMount() method, is that method will be automatically executed? @BensSteves

Comment: yes your componenetDidMount will execute automatically. The return statement in the map function is just for the map function. Its a return statement for that function. But react requires a return statement after your render(){ ... If you leave that out, react has no clue what to do or how to interpret your map function

Comment: you can search lifecycle methods on react's documentation website to get a better understanding of each one. Here's the link: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-lifecycle-methods-to-a-class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the return statement after `render`

```
render() {
    const { error, isLoaded, items } = this.state;
    return (
     <div>
      {
       items.map(key => {
        return (
          <Text key={key.id}>
            {key.id}
          </Text>
        )
      })
    }
   </div>
  }
 )
}
```

that's it should be good to go.

Note: remember when you map something the outer most element or your root element in the return statement of the map function *must* include a *unique key*. Since I assume your `key.id` is unique, you can use that as your unique key.

Updated Answer:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    error: null,
    isLoaded: false,
    items: [
      { id: 1, name: "Apples", price: "$2" },
      { id: 2, name: "Peaches", price: "$5" }
    ]
  };
  componentWillMount() {
    this.setState({ items: [...this.state.items, { id: 3 }] }, () => {
      this.displayItems(this.state.items);
    });
  }
  displayItems = items => {
    console.log(items);
    return items.map(key => {
      return <div key={key.id}>{key.id}</div>;
    });
  };
  render() {
    const { items } = this.state;
    return <div>{this.displayItems(items)}</div>;
  }
}

export default App;
```

The I changed didMount to WillMount(). The WillMount() will mount (pun not intended) before anything is rendered. Then the component will render the map function. So the state is updated. I sent the items from the WillMount() to a new function displayItems for extra assurance that the state will update. Hope this helps.

**Edit: WARNING**

I used WillMount() here but I did not include UNSAFE. `componentWillMount()` will no longer work after version 17. You can use `UNSAFE_componentWillMount()`. That will work through version 17. Sorry about that (I'm used to just picking that from IntelliSense).

Comment: the bracket right inside outter return statement produce error

Comment: ah yes thank you. You need a root div or a root element in every return statement. sorry about that.

Comment: you can't have more than one root element. so see the div...you can only have one outer div you can't have adjacent div's like <div>...map function</div><div></div>. This is a no no in react. you would get a parsing error cannot have adjacent jsx elements. or jsx elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag. mind you, I'm just using div as an example it can be any element.

Comment: Hmm now I have new error. My items object is undefined. Can you figure out again what's wrong?

Comment: where have you set your items? or where have you defined items? not the const { items} = this.state part but where in your source did you actually assign items a value

Comment: inside componentDidMount(). Right after I got the ajax response, I call setState method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184944/discussion-between-bens-steves-and-hendro-febrian).